# How long does it take to drink a water bottle in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm working on a project in Minecraft, and for me to do it I need to know the exact time it takes to drink a water bottle. Does anyone know?

Comment: What is keeping you from drinking a water bottle and keeping an eye on your watch?

Comment: Also @ScottChamberlain, counting isn't the most efficient way. From memory (I counted *ages* ago), it was 4 seconds. But when I compared the number of times it plays the eating sound, to the **length** of the eating sound - I was a whole second off.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain because I wanted the exact time, not something close to it. Anyone can say 3-4 seconds, but not everybody can say 3.27. Close isn't good enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The eating sounds (which are the same for both potions and food) last for approximate 0.5 seconds. However, they are not simply played once.
*(Obviously the eating animation lasts for more than 0.5 seconds)*

So, when you eat food, it plays 6 times. So, it takes approximately 3 seconds to consume food.
This also applies to potions/bottled water. It plays 6 times. Therefore: It takes 3 seconds to drink water.

**Edit:** 3.5 seconds (70 ticks), based on evidence in: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/191222/75275

Comment: I doubt this answer is exact, because each sound is cut by the next one. You can hear the end of the sound once you finish eating/drinking, so if that counts in the .5 seconds, the total time is actually shorter.

Comment: Agreed. I actually noticed that, but I don't know the exact delay it plays the sound over each other. (It's about 0.2s?)

Answer (score 2):

What better way than to measure from inside the game itself ? None, sir.

[image: Screenshot of the experiment setup]
(Click to enlarge)

From right to left :

- A simple fill clock, running at 20Hz
  `setblock ~ ~1 ~ air` / `setblock ~ ~-1 ~ redstone_block`
- A command block incrementing my `timer` score if I'm in possession of a water bottle
  `/scoreboard players add @p timer 1 {Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:potion"}]}`
- A command block resetting my timer
  `scoreboard players set @p timer 0`
- A command block giving me a water bottle
  `give @p potion`

For the experiment I switch to `gamemode 0`. When I press the button and "drag" away from it, it sets the timer to zero, then gives me a water bottle. The bottle lands in my first free hotbar slot, which I have selected beforehand. This way I start drinking it right away, while the clock counts up. Once I drank it all, the water bottle is replaced by an empty bottle, and no longer triggers the counter. Thus, the timer indicates how long it has taken me to drink the water.

The results over 20 samples were :

```
Clk   N°
36    1
35    15
34    3
32    1
```

Barring a slight variation whose cause is unknown, the time to drink a water bottle is 35 * 1/20 = 1.75 seconds.

**Edit**: the same protocol applied to a standard cooked porkchop has shown similar results.

Comment: Don't you think 1.75 seconds is a little too fast? (Also, to point out; the fastest possible clock is only 10 Hz; it takes a tick to place, another to break.. And since there are 20 ticks in a second, this can only be repeated 10 times in a single second.)

Comment: @aytimothy the fill clock works on a quirk : the world state is not buffered, so both command blocks actually act in the same game tick, at 20Hz. And counting manually, "a bit short of 2 seconds" seems right indeed (try the "mississippi" trick to refrain from counting too fast :p)